# Bash Command Line: networksetup: Command Not Found (OS X)

Tags: terminal, bash

After editing my .bash_profile to export a path, my terminal stopped recognizing even simple commands such as "ls" and "vi".

The error message that I see is:

```
-bash: networksetup: command not found
```

[image: See image]

I don't know if I caused this error by editing  my .bash_profile, and since I haven't been able to open any files via the terminal, I can't delete what I last added.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update / Solution:

The problem was in the .bash_profile. I downloaded [Secrets](https://code.google.com/p/blacktree-secrets/downloads/detail?name=Secrets_1.0.6.zip&can=2&q=), which allowed me to see hidden files. With that, I could open my .bash_profile.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command.

> /usr/bin/vim .bash_profile

PATH variable defines the list of directories for where the executable for the given command will be searched for. Since the PATH variable is not set the system does not know where executable for the given commands (ls, vi, etc) are located